# Trying to calculate E(x) and Var(x), what am I doing wrong?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expectation

This is the question:

A and B are two competing companies. An investor decides whether to buy

(a) 100 shares of A, or

(b) 100 shares of B, or

(c) 50 shares of A and 50 shares of B.

A profit made on 1 share of A is a random variable X with the distribution P (X = 2) =
P (X = −2) = 0.5.

A profit made on 1 share of B is a random variable Y with the distribution P(Y = 4) =
0.2,P(Y = −1) = 0.8.

If X and Y are independent, compute the expected value and variance of the total profit
for strategies (a), (b), and (c).

Here is what I have:

E(aX) = aE(X) and 
Var(aX) = a^2Var(X)

a) E(X) = .5*2 + .5*-2 = 0 so aE(X) = 0

Var(X) = 100^2((.5)*(2-0)^2 + (.5)*(-2-0)^2) = 40,000

b) E(Y) = 4*.2 + 1*.8 = 0 so aE(Y) = 0

Var(Y) = 100^2((.2)*(4-0)^2 + (.8)*(-1-0)^2) = 40,000

c) (independent) so E(aX + bY) = aE(X) + bE(Y) = 0

independent so Var(aX + bY) = a^2Var(X) + b^2Var(Y)

50^2((.2)*(4-0)^2 + (.8)*(-1-0)^2) = 10,000
50^2((.5)*(2-0)^2 + (.5)*(-2-0)^2) = 10,000

so Var(aX + bY) = 20,000

I'm asking this question because these values seem way off. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I am going by definitions and properties outlines in the textbook.

Comment: 1: use mathjax, 2: ask shorter and clearer.

Comment: The assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are independent does not imply that the expectation of their sum is 0.  Indeed, for random variables $X$ and $Y$, $\operatorname{E}\left[X + Y\right] = \operatorname{E}[X] + \operatorname{E}[Y]$.

Comment: E[X] was equal to 0 and so was E[Y]. I'm more concerned, though, about the very large variance.

Comment: The variance is high because $Var(100X)=10\ 000Var(X)$ as you calculated well.